# Replace characters with space in Sublime text 3

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext3

I am trying to replace T and Z with space using Sublime text editor in the following line :

2013-12-26T23:24:42Z

I searched for T and Z and replaced it with " ", but it actually replaces it literally with " "
like this :

2013-12-26" "23:24:42Z" ".
in the place of T and Z.
Can someone please tell me how to include a space?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the replace dialog (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> or via the menu "Find" -> "Replace"):

Simply literally enter a blank in the "Replace With:" field, by setting the cursor in it and hitting the space key on your keyboard.

In Sublime 3, there is no need to "escape" that blank in any way, as you tried.